# How we can arrange react-select heading and corresponding combo box horizontally?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select

It's been 3-4 hours I am trying to arrange Select Component and its heading horizontally but somehow could not get that working. To elaborate I used following code to achieve this functionality :

```css
.horizontal {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid green
}

.horizontal * {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div className="horizontal">
  <h3 className="section-heading">{this.props.label}</h3>
  <Select id="state-select" ref="stateSelect" autoFocus options={options} simpleValue clearable={this.state.clearable} name="selected-state" disabled={this.state.disabled} value={this.state.selectValue} onChange={this.updateValue} rtl={this.state.rtl} searchable={this.state.searchable}
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if this works.

```
<div style={{display: "flex"}}>
    <h3 className="section-heading">{this.props.label}</h3>
    <div style={{width: "55%"}}>    
        <Select
            id="state-select"
            ref="stateSelect"
            autoFocus
            options={options}
            simpleValue
            clearable={this.state.clearable}
            name="selected-state"
            disabled={this.state.disabled}
            value={this.state.selectValue}
            onChange={this.updateValue}
            rtl={this.state.rtl}
            searchable={this.state.searchable}
        />
    </div>
</div>
```